# Cannot achieve the reported accuracy with tensorflow wide_n_deep_tutorial?

Tags: model, tensorflow

I'm learning the google's wide&deep model these days with its tensorflow tutorial. After running the code in ["wide_n_deep_tutorial.py"](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py)!, I achieved accuracy 0.834 for wide-only model, but the achieved accuracy for wide-and-deep model was only about 0.82.

I didn't change anything in the source code and just couldn't achieve the accuracy 0.844 as reported on its website.

Has anyone met the same problem with me? And does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to run for longer? (`train_steps`)

Comment: Thanks, it works!